# How to resolve "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" error

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have the following code:

```java
public class MergeDuplicatesController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> findContacts(String searchValue, Boolean selected, Boolean  isPrime, Integer length) {
        searchValue = '%'+searchValue+'%';
        //List<ContactWrapper> ContactList = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        //integer i = 1;
        List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE : searchValue];
        for(Contact con : conList){
            ContactWrapper wr = new ContactWrapper();
            wr.isPrime = isPrime;
            wr.selected = selected;
            conList.add(wr);            
        }
        return conList;
    }   
    public class ContactWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean selected;
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean isPrime;
        @AuraEnabled
        public Contact con;
    }
}
```

But it's throwing the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>
> ```
> void add(MergeDuplicatesController.ContactWrapper)
> ```
>
> from the type `List<Contact>`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `List<Contact> conList`. List of Contacts. It accepts only objects of class `Contact`. You can't add to this list a `ContactWrapper` because it's not a Contact, it doesn't extend (inherit from) Contact...

You **probably** need something like this

```
public static List<ContactWrapper> findContacts(String searchValue, Boolean selected, Boolean  isPrime, Integer length) {
        searchValue = '%'+searchValue+'%';
        List<ContactWrapper> ret = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE : searchValue];
        for(Contact con : conList){
            ContactWrapper wr = new ContactWrapper();
            wr.con = con;
            wr.isPrime = isPrime;
            wr.selected = selected;
            ret.add(wr);            
        }
        return ret ;
    }
```